# How do you install android apps on an android device from windows 8?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-8, libgdx

I have created a game using libgdx and would like to test the game on my android phone. I have done my research but there seems to be no information on installing android apps when running windows 8. More specifically: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html there is no way to get around this part of the installation process on windows 8. As well as there is no documentation or information about installing android apps in the libgdx documentation from what i could find. if anyone could offer any insight that would be great. thanks again

Comment: libgdx documentation doesn't have any of this because it's done exactly the same as any other Android app. I think you can just follow the Windows 7 instructions. The OEM USB driver is only for certain devices. For most devices you just need the USB driver from the phone/tablet manufacturer's web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the apk file. Go into the android project section of the libgdx project and click the bin folder. there should be an apk file in there that you can send to you phone any way you want to. Then you can install the file on the phone directly. You can also look into the usb tool that you posted and find the correct one for your specific phone and then you could just run it in eclipse if you have the android sdk installed.